# How to update and remove Pkexec executable

Tags: updates, uninstall, pkexec, vulnerability

I came to [know](https://youtu.be/eTcVLqKpZJc) that most linux distros(including Ubuntu) have a vulnerability due to PKEXEC. The advice that is given to be safe is to either update the polkit or remove the Pkexec executable.

My questions are:

1. How can i update to the latest version of polkit so that i won't have the vulnerability.
2. How can i remove the executable completely so that no one can use that old executable to take advantage of the said vulnerability.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and when i get the following output when i run the command `locate pkexec`:

```
/snap/core18/2284/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.dpkg.pkexec.update-alternatives.policy
/snap/core18/2344/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.dpkg.pkexec.update-alternatives.policy
/snap/core20/1376/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.dpkg.pkexec.update-alternatives.policy
/snap/core20/1405/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.dpkg.pkexec.update-alternatives.policy
/usr/bin/pkexec
/usr/share/man/man1/pkexec.1.gz
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.dpkg.pkexec.update-alternatives.policy
```

Comment: My advice: a little patience until Ubuntu developers fix that for you.

Comment: @vanadium 
Isn't there a way to remove it for the time being(till the Ubuntu developers fix this)?

Comment: Isn't it already patched? see https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-4034 and check your policykit-1 version - my Ubuntu 18.04 box appear to be at 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6 already

Comment: @steeldriver After executing the command `pkaction --version` i get the output as: `pkaction version 0.105`. Is this the correct way to check the policykit-1's version? Is there any other commad to check the policykit1's version? For example your policykit1 version output seems a little different than mine.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the package version - either `apt policy policykit-1` or `dpkg -l policykit-1`. You can also run `apt-get changelog policykit-1` - the first entry should describe the patch.

Comment: @steeldriver When i execute: `apt-get changelog policykit-1`, then i get the output: `Get:1 https://changelogs.ubuntu.com policykit-1 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6 Changelog [31.8 kB]
Fetched 31.8 kB in 2s (17.6 kB/s)`. And when i execute: `apt policy policykit-1` i get the output: `Installed: 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6
  Candidate: 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6`. So, from the output of the second command(`apt policy policykit-1`), i think i have the patched version installed. But i don't understand the meaning of the output given by the command: `apt-get changelog policykit-1`.

Comment: Can you describe what is the meaning of the output `Get:1 https://changelogs.ubuntu.com policykit-1 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6 Changelog [31.8 kB]
Fetched 31.8 kB in 2s (17.4 kB/s)`. I mean i thought that it should search my local pc for the current installed version, but looking at the output it seems it read/fetched file from web.

Comment: For reference (I came across this post whilst searching for something else related to pkexec and it peeked my interest!!) this is the text you'd be looking for, that @steeldriver suggests you check:
`* SECURITY UPDATE: Local Privilege Escalation in pkexec
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-4034.patch: properly handle command-line
      arguments in src/programs/pkcheck.c, src/programs/pkexec.c.
    - CVE-2021-4034
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can check at [Ubuntu Security - CVE-2021-4034](https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2021-4034), the bug has already been patched by the maintainers.

To upgrade to the patched version (that's `0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6` in the case of Ubuntu "Bionic"), you don't need to do anything more than apply your system's regular security updates.

You can check if you are already running the patched version using `apt`:

```
$ apt policy policykit-1
policykit-1:
  Installed: 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6
  Candidate: 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6
  Version table:
 *** 0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.105-20 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

or with `dpkg`:

```
$ dpkg -l policykit-1
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                      Version                   Architecture              Description
+++-=========================================-=========================-=========================-=======================================================================================
ii  policykit-1                               0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6   amd64                     framework for managing administrative policies and privileges
```

(`policykit-1` being the package that provides the `pkexec` binary, as you can confirm using `dpkg -S /usr/bin/pkexec`).

You can view the patch report in the package's changelog:

```
$ apt changelog policykit-1
policykit-1 (0.105-20ubuntu0.18.04.6) bionic-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: Local Privilege Escalation in pkexec
    - debian/patches/CVE-2021-4034.patch: properly handle command-line
      arguments in src/programs/pkcheck.c, src/programs/pkexec.c.
    - CVE-2021-4034

 -- Marc Deslauriers <marc.deslauriers@ubuntu.com>  Wed, 12 Jan 2022 07:34:00 -0500
```